# Excel VBA close function only saves to desktop, how do I change the save location?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file in a floder thats inside another folder, that is on the desktop. I am using

```
dimbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

with dimbook is my current workbook in order to close and save the workbook, and it works fine, except I expected it to save to the same folder as the workbook using the macro, when in fact it saves to the desktop. How can I specify the save location? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to use the save as functionality:

`dimbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\path"`

Then 
`dimbook.Close` //etc etc